# Distance between a parametric equation and a normal equation

Tags: linear-algebra

L is a line with parametric equations `x = 3t, y = -4, z = 5 - 2t`. P is a plane with `2x - 4y + 3z = 1` as its normal equation.

How do I find the distance between these two equations?

Comment: How would you find the distance between a point and plane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your geometric primitives have the following equations

$$ \begin{aligned}
  \text{line} & &  \text{plane} \\
  \vec{r}  & = \vec{p} + t\,\vec{e} &  \vec{r}\cdot \vec{n} & = c \\
  \pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z}  & = \pmatrix{0 \\ -4 \\ 5} + t \pmatrix{3 \\ 0 \\ -2} 
& \pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z} \cdot \pmatrix{2 \\ -4 \\ 3}  & = 1
\end{aligned}  $$

The geometrical interpretation of the above quantities is as follows:

- $\vec{p}$ is a point on the line.
- $\vec{r}$ is a vector along the line.
- $\vec{n}$ is a vector normal to the plane.
- $c$ is proportional to the distance of the plane (and any point on it) to the origin.

If the line is parallel to the plane, it means that no component of $\vec{e}$ is along $\vec{n}$, or $\vec{e} \cdot \vec{n} = 0 $

To find the distance of a point to a plane, project the point along the plane normal to measure the distance of the point to the origin along the plane normal and subtract the distance of the plane.

$$ d = \frac{\vec{n} \cdot \vec{p}}{\| \vec{n} \|} - \frac{c}{\| \vec{n} \|} $$

Here I chose $\vec{p}$ for the measuring point because it is guaranteed to belong to the line.

<sub>The vector $\vec{n} / \| \vec{n} \|$ is the plane normal, as a unit vector (with the vector length in the denomintor) which is used to measure distances perpendicular to the plane.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that your line is parallel to your given plane.
It is $$[3,0,-2]\cdot [2,-4,3]=...$$
and convert the equation of your plane into the Hessian Normalform,
$$\frac{2x-4y+3z-1}{\pm\sqrt{4+16+9}}=0$$